# Use HTML id value in PHP array

Tags: php, html

I have an array that displays images. I want to make each image clickable to display that specific image larger on an overlaying div.

Each image is displayed and has a different id which is being generated with this code:

```
<?php if (count($images) > 0) : ?>
<?php $i = 0; ?>

<?php foreach($images as $image) : ?>


       <div class=" item" onclick="showOverlay()" id="<?= $i; ?>"><img class="photo" src="<?= $image; ?>"></div>

    <?php $i++; ?>   
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The image in the overlaying div must now use the id value to determine which array item (image) to display.

This is my code that does not work.

```
<div class="overlay">

<?php

$dirname = "img/photos/$student/$entry/*.JPG";
$images = glob($dirname);

?>  

<img src="<?= $images[$_POST['id']]; ?>">
```

Comment: You cannot do this with your existing code in php

Comment: where is the code of your "overlaying div" and why do you use `$_POST`? is there anything posted to your website?

Comment: Ok how else would I do it? @Mayank Pandeyz

Comment: I'm not sure which code you are talking about? The overlaying div's code is the second block of code. I'm still new at php so I thought I had to use $_POST. What should I be using?

Comment: I don't even know what you are trying to achieve with your code. you can try to do the same loop in your overlay-div, because you are basically doing the same thing.

Comment: The overlaying div must only display the image that was selected. Not the whole array. So the image source of the overlaying div's image must display the array item that was selected.